# Get json value from a function that has an ajax call in it

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm trying to get json value from a function that has an ajax call in it.

This is my function:

```
function getVariables(){

     $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "db/functions.php",
      data: "func=getvars,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response)
      {        
        return { 
          'var1': response.var1,
          'var2': response.var2
        };
      }
    });     
}
```

I am trying to use this in my javascript to get var1
var firstvar = getVariables().var1;

when I set an alert in getVariables function it returns var1 and var2, already checked that out. So the only part which is not working properly is: var firstvar = getVariables().var1;

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with this:

Ajax calls, by default, are asynchronous. This means that the success function will not be invoked until sometime after `getVariables` has returned. You need to alter the settings of you ajax call so that it is synchronous.

Your second problem is that the values are returned from the success function, but that does not return them from the `getVariables` function. You need to return the variables from function scope.

Below is the same function, but with the `async` option set to false and with the values returned from the function's scope.

```
function getVariables(){
     var rv = undefined;
     $.ajax({
      async : false,
      type: "post",
      url: "db/functions.php",
      data: "func=getvars",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response)
      {        
        rv = { 
          'var1': response.var1,
          'var2': response.var2
        };
      }
    });     
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: @nouky - that is most likely a syntax error: mispelling a function or having mismatched brackets. Can't help you on that one - try running it in IE9 with the F12 developer tools, see if it can help you.

Comment: @nouky - I realised there was still a bug in what I gave you. I've edited it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous success function returns `var1` and `var2` (to nowhere), but getVariables is not returning them.  It cannot in fact, because it has exited before the asynchronous JSON call is complete.  Even if it was synchronous, you still aren't returning the return value of the anonymous "sub-function".

EDIT: You could do something like this:

```
function getVariables(){

    var response = $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "db/functions.php",
      data: "func=getvars,
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
    });
    return {'var1': response.var1,
            'var2': response.var2}  
}
```

See how the return statement is now in `getVariables`, not in a function INSIDE getVariables?  So now getVariables will return the values.

Although be careful of using async: false, it can lock the browser.

Comment: if I add: async : false
will it not help??

Comment: If you *also* move the return statement, it should work.  See my edit above.

Comment: I am getting undefined variable.. I guess I need to post the whole code so you can get a better understanding of whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work.  The AJAX call is asynchronous, and needs to wait for the http request to complete before you can use it's return values.

You can make the AJAX call synchronous, but that's probably going to introduce an unnecessary delay.  Typically the better option is to use the variables directly in your callback "success" function.

Comment: i want to return the values so I can use them in different situations, for example one time as text other time as a value in an input etc etc

Comment: While I think you can make it work by making the ajax call synchronous, then you'd be making an http request each time you call getVariables().  You can push the data returned data into a scope that's more accessible, but it's hard for someone to offer code without a more complete idea of your goal.

Comment: I'm going to post my whole code online, so you can get a better view of the scenario